# Statistical test for large unequal sample size

Tags: dataset

I have 2 groups: N=350 (G1) and N=1,500(G2). G1 refers to 1 company and G2 is a group of 4 companies.
Is z test appropriate to test the significant differences between percentage distribution?, i.e. if 51/49% male/female in G1 is significantly different than 46%/54% male/female in G2?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you're referring to the *Z* test of the difference between independent proportions.  Btw in this situation you can also use a Chi-Square test and you'll get  the same *p*-value but you won't be able to generate a confidence interval for the population difference.